# MAUI - After Launcher.OpenAsync, app returns to main window

Tags: android, modal-dialog, maui, launcher, url-launcher

I've got an application that has structure like that:

**Main View with menu** --press button--> **List View** --select item from listview--> **Modal window**.

Each modal window contains **button**, that **launches youtube video**:

`await Launcher.Default.OpenAsync(new Uri($"vnd.youtube://{link}"));`

Same behaviour if i try to open document:

`await Browser.Default.OpenAsync(new Uri(link.ToString())`

Even though youtube video opens, when i go back to application it is back to Main View.
How can i force app to stay in the same view when Launcher is executed?

Note: It did work as intended on Xamarin.Forms...

EDIT: Button/Image code in xaml:

```xml
<Image Grid.Row="9" Grid.Column="1" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="Start" IsVisible="{Binding HasDocumentLink}" Source="pdf_icon" >
 <Image.GestureRecognizers>
   <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Document_Tapped" CommandParameter="{Binding BoardGame.TutorialLink}" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
 </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
```

And full method in view model:

```cs
private void Document_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var link = ((TappedEventArgs)e).Parameter;
  Browser.Default.OpenAsync(new Uri(link.ToString()), BrowserLaunchMode.SystemPreferred);
}
```

EDIT2:
On request, also ItemTemplate for opening modal window:

```xml
<Grid.GestureRecognizers>
  <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding BindingContext.TapCommand, Source={x:Reference BoardGamesView}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
 </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
```

Viewmodel:

```cs
private void OnItemTapped(BoardGame boardGame)
{
 App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new BoardGamePage(boardGame), false);
}
```

Comment: Please send the code behind the button. Do you have any code on resume?

Comment: Button xaml part (actually it is an image, not actual button - forgot about it) added in EDIT part

Comment: Also send the code when you tap the item on listview. The code that opens the modal window.

Comment: Added both xaml and method in viewmodel

Comment: As you coming from xamarin forms there are some workarounds. 1st Use Shell.Current.GoToAsync instead of PushModalAsync, and if you indeed need modal try popup https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pop-ups

Comment: Why would transforming to Shell navigation fix anything? Is it a suggested navigation handling on MAUI?

Comment: I read that this is the recommended way. I cant recall the link right now, but it's worth trying.